# Sharepoint Calculated Column If Statement Evaluation

Tags: sharepoint-2010, calculated-columns

I have a calculated column that always evaluates to true even when it should and I can't figure out why.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, here is the column:

```
=[Name]&" "&IF([num1]>0,"("&[num1]&")","")&" "&IF([num2]>0,"("&[num2]&")","")
```

So I it should show num1 if it is > 0 and num2 if that is > 0 but it shows them both all the time regardless of their values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you **very very** sure [num1] and [num2] are both numbers?

Because

```
=IF("-1">0,...
```

will evaluate to true

```
=ISNUMBER([num1])&ISNUMBER([num2])
```

should return

```
TRUETRUE
```

if any of the two return FALSE

there is your problem.

This will cast strings to numbers:

```
=IF(VALUE(num1)>0,"("
&num1
&")","")
&" "
&IF(VALUE(num2)>0,"("
&num2
&")","")
```

*square brackets are only required when there are spaces in the column names*